# pyglet - Retrieve width of Label

Tags: python, pyglet

I have a label element for displaying text on the screen:

```
nameLabel = pyglet.text.Label(name, font_name='Tahoma', x=50, y=50, font_size=12, batch=batch.overlay2, height=self.scale_y, bold=True)
```

With the label I also have a `pyglet.sprite.Sprite`:

```
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(res.IMG_COLOR_BLACK, batch=batch.overlay1)
```

The image of this sprite is 1x1 pixels and I am using the scale_x and scale_y values to draw a rectangle.

I would like to set the width of this sprite to the width of the text, so that the text fits inside it.

I have tried using `Label.width`:

```
sprite.scale_x = nameLabel.width
```

However, the width is only returning `None` and therefore raising an error.

I can't think of any other way to retrieve the width of this label. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use the content width and content height attributes. It should return the width and the height of the label rectangle.

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(1280, 720, "Labels", resizable=False)

text = pyglet.text.Label("hello earthlings from space", x=640, y=360)
text.italic = True
text.bold = True
text.color = (255, 200, 150, 255)
text.font_size = 20
print(text.content_width)
print(text.content_height)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    text.draw()

def update(dt):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0/60)
    pyglet.app.run()
```